# Mirroring and expanding display on Arch with xfce -Display Settings

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, monitors

I have 3 monitors plugged into my PC. I want to have one primary display one expanded display and the third one should be mirrored from the primary display. 
Is there a way to solve this on xfce?